# How to stop the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent receiver when i close that application?

Tags: android, nfc

i filter the intent like this

```
<intent-filter>    
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
```

now the problem is, when i discover the Ndef tag near to my mobile the event which i implemented in my application is running(even my application at close state).
How to stop this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ForegroundDispatchSystem.

Example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/nfc/ForegroundDispatch.html

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best solution is using NFC foreground dispatching. But turning the Intent filter in the manifest file off can be accomplished through the use of an [`<activity-alias>` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-alias-element.html) in the manifest. By putting the Intent filter in the `<activity-alias>` instead of the `<activity>` element itself, you can disable and enable it at will in your app.

So suppose you have in your manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="your.app.package">
  ...
  <activity-alias android:name=".yourActivityAlias"
      android:enabled="true" android:targetActivity=".yourActivity">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity-alias>
  ....
</manifest>
```

Then you can disable the `<activity-alias>` from an activity in your app through:

```
PackageManager pkgMgr = getPackageManager();
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("your.app.package", "your.app.package.yourActivityAlias");
pkgMgr.setComponentEnabledSetting(comp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Please, note that the new setting only takes effect upon restarting the app (so you may want to consider 0 instead of PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP). Also, it often takes a little while for the packagemanager to make the new setting effective (probably depends on the processing speed of the device).

Comment: Now im using your code only... i implemented this in application exit option... but this code is not stopping the application process... i want to stop the application.....

Comment: i used that also, but the application is not stopping

 PackageManager pkgMgr = getPackageManager();
                ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.usa.sis", "com.usa.sis.NFCActivity");
                pkgMgr.setComponentEnabledSetting(comp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                  0);
                finish();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                   System.exit(0);

This is my code....